# How do I configure Acrobat Pro 9 Preference settings for all users on a Windows 2003 terminal server?

Tags: windows

I have Adobe Acrobat Pro 9 installed on a Windows 2003 terminal server.  How can I make Preference setting changes that will affect all users?

Answer (score 0):

Aside from creating a custom install package and (re)installing it on all the computers, you may want to consider [PolicyPak](http://www.policypak.com), which adds preference settings for many programs to the Group Policy system of Windows.

> With PolicyPak, you can ensure that when users log on, they are
>   getting exactly the desktop, application and security settings they
>   are supposed to get, without leaving it up to chance, or worse,
>   leaving the configuration in the hands of the user. With PolicyPak you
>   can be confident that "What you SET is what they GET."
>   PolicyPak is standards compliant and uses Active Directory and Group Policy (or SCCM or your own 
>   management tool) to deliver the settings.

They have a specific pack for Acrobat (X) Reader and Standard, [see here](http://www.policypak.com/products/manage-acrobat-x-pro-and-acrobat-x-standard-using-group-policy.html).

Example of preferences you can control.

> - Update behavior (turning it off, so users aren't prompted)
> - Turn off dangerous items like Javascript
> - Ensure Acrobat "Enhanced Security" is turned on

*Note: I have no affiliation with PolicyPak's authors, but I've used the product in the past and it worked as advertised for us.*